# Is it possible to get 3-way data binding in an AngularJS application using Parse?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, firebase

I'm following a tutorial for building a web application using Firebase as the backend, which has the advantage of providing 3-way data binding so that any updates to the data store are reflected in the view transparently and vice versa. Is this possible with Parse as well and if so where can I read about it?

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box from what I've read:
https://www.parse.com/questions/real-time-chat-app-with-just-only-parse

http://www.quora.com/Parse-cloud-backend/Is-it-possible-to-use-Parse-com-for-realtime-chat-like-Socket-io

https://parse.com/questions/real-time-updates-like-firebase

Seems any solution is going to require leveraging pusher/pubnub,etc.

Googled "parse.com chat app"  | "parse realtime chat"